# importing another css file from a css file under public asset does not work for play 2.0.4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, playframework, assets, public

I am pretty new to play and I am trying to use play 2.0.4 scala version with twitter bootstrap. I also got a theme from wrapbootstrap. The theme has certain customized css files which i put under public/stylesheets.

I end up with two css files under public/stylesheets: style.css and icons.css.  The style.css imports icons.css using @import url("icon.css").

so I thought everything should work if I just link style.css in my index.scala.html using:
 
But the play framework can not find icon.css.  I have to explicitly link icon.css inside index.scala.html with

I am not sure how play framwork takes care of the path issue for importing another css file inside of a css file under public assets.  I'd appreciate if somebody can shed some light on this.

Best,
James

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing about Play, all files which you put inside `public` folder are accessible without any additional processing.

Proper way for importing CSS inside of CSS is:

```
@import url("icons.css");
```

so if you add a semicolon at the end it will probably start working.

- Remember, that `@import` rule must be placed at the beginning of the CSS file, you can't put even single line comment before it!
- Make sure that your both stylesheets has some code inside, also restart application if required and/or purge the browser's cache.
- Finally use developers tools such as Firebug in FireFox to examine what paths to the files was created, I know that's very low possibility, but maybe you... made a typo in file's name.